# Laravel collection for associative array

Tags: laravel, collections

This is the array that I am trying to convert to collections and pluck the values.

```
$arr = [
         "TID" => "81226042",
         "TLineID" => "81226042",
         "Sales" => [
            [
               "TLineID" => "226041"
            ],
            [
               "TLineID" => "226042"
            ],
            [
               "TLineID" => "9042"
            ]
         ]
      ];
//$r = collect($arr)->pluck('Sales');
$r = collect(json_decode(json_encode($arr)))->pluck('Sales');

print_r($r->toArray());
```

the output I get is

```
Array
(
    [0] =>
    [1] =>
    [2] =>
)
```

I am expecting the 'Sales' Array here.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is for you https://rextester.com/TOMA34434

Comment: do you get your expected output with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your doing wrong

```php
$arr = [
    [
        "TID" => "81226042",
        "TLineID" => "81226042",
        "Sales" => [
            [
                "TLineID" => "226041"
            ],
            [
                "TLineID" => "226042"
            ],
            [
                "TLineID" => "9042"
            ]
        ]
    ],
    [
        "TID" => "81226042",
        "TLineID" => "81226042",
        "Sales" => [
            [
                "TLineID" => "226041"
            ],
            [
                "TLineID" => "226042"
            ],
            [
                "TLineID" => "9042"
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

$sales = collect($arr)->pluck('Sales')->toArray(); 
dd($sales);
```

i think this your trying to achieve

Comment: oh i created base on that array let me do multiple

Comment: "your doing wrong" and "[try this]" is not a great way to educate the asker and thousands of future researchers.  Please [edit] this answer to be more helpful to researchers.